# Change menu link before rendered in mmenu module

Tags: routes, hooks

I've used [Mobile sliding menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/mmenu) module version 7.x-1.0-dev.

We can change menu link using `theme_menu_link()`.

Similarly is any other hook for change menu link in this module?

Answer (score 1):

You want to implement [hook_translated_menu_link_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_translated_menu_link_alter/7) and [hook_menu_link_alter(&$item)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_link_alter/7). This hook is not called for all menu items.

According to the API documentation:

It is only invoked if $item['options']['alter'] has been set to a non-empty value (e.g., TRUE). This flag should be set using hook_menu_link_alter().
Here's an example:

```
function MODULE_menu_link_alter(&$link) {
  if ($link['link_title'] == 'foo') {
    $link['options']['alter'] = TRUE;
  }
}

function MODULE_translated_menu_link_alter(&$link) {
  if ($link['link_title'] == 'foo') {
    $link['href'] = 'node/5';
  }
}
```

#### Some notes

You may want to filter additionally by $link['menu_name']; MODULE_menu_link_alter() is invoked on cache clear for all menus items declared via hook_menu().
For menu items created via web it is only invoked on save, that is, for this code to take effect you need to edit-and-save menu links you want to alter.